# Multiple where selection (high number of params) in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to select a column of a table with a query similar to that

```
select * from table where id= (2,5,7,32,21,76......);
```

that where clause is invalid but reflexes what I want. Is there a short notation for doing that or shall I use

```
    select * from table where id= 2 or id=5 or id =7 .......;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tables where id in (2, 5, 7, 32, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer hmmm im a little lost with sqlite in Adnroid any idea how to implement it in the SQLiteDatabase class at the update method?